ERC721InsufficientApproval after using setApprovalForAll
In my Hardhat project, I'm trying to send an NFT between a bunch of different addresses (for fun).  I've been doing it this way:
  const myAddress = "0x06b0ED5338e36623b859081B0692F7dE33aF67E5";
  const firstRecipient = "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266";
  const secondRecipient = "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8";
  //-- a bunch of code to mint an nft

  await myNFTContract.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, firstRecipient, 0);
  await myNFTContract.safeTransferFrom(firstRecipient, secondRecipient, 0);

However, when I try to move the nft from the first to the second recipient, I get this error:
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC721InsufficientApproval("0x06b0ED5338e36623b859081B0692F7dE33aF67E5", 0)'

However, if I add this line into my code:
  await myNFTContract.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, firstRecipient, 0);
  //--v here
  await myNFTContract.setApprovalForAll(myAddress, true);
  await myNFTContract.safeTransferFrom(firstRecipient, secondRecipient, 0);

I still get the error.  What am I doing wrong?
Here's a GitHub repo you can try it out on: https://github.com/aaronzshey/setapproval-mr
Here's the complete error output:
ProviderError: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC721InsufficientApproval("0x06b0ED5338e36623b859081B0692F7dE33aF67E5", 0)'
    at HttpProvider.request (/Users/aaron/setapproval-mr/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:96:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (/Users/aaron/setapproval-mr/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/src/signers.ts:125:18)
    at async send (/Users/aaron/setapproval-mr/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:313:20)
    at async Proxy.safeTransferFrom (/Users/aaron/setapproval-mr/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:352:16)
    at async main (/Users/aaron/setapproval-mr/index.ts:40:3)


On my end, it's working fine though. Can you add the full stack trace of error in your question?

@SYEDASADKAZMI I've updated the post with a full error message!

Okay. And, can you please confirm that you're executing the exact same code as you've shared in index.ts file?
